# Maven: Log4j class not found

Tags: java, maven, junit, module, log4j2

I have a project for which I've added an optional dependency to Log4j:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.19.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

In my module descriptor, I've added requirements for both the implementation and the API:

```java
    requires static org.apache.logging.log4j;
    requires static org.apache.logging.log4j.core;
```

If I build the project as a pre-module project, the projects builds successfully. However, when I build  the project as a module, JUnit fails. While initially the error wasn't clear, adding `-e` to the Maven command shows the following error:

```
TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:132)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:107)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncherSession.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.discover(LazyLauncher.java:48)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.TestPlanScannerFilter.accept(TestPlanScannerFilter.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.api.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:102)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.scanClasspath(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:139)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger.Log4jLoggerContextTest'] resolution failed
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:103)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:83)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:46)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Supplier
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1096)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:206)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:759)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassInModuleOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:680)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:605)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309)
        at org.junit.platform.commons@1.9.0/org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1494)
        at org.junit.platform.commons@1.9.0/org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:1343)
        at org.junit.platform.commons@1.9.0/org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.isMethodPresent(ReflectionUtils.java:1244)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.hasTestOrTestFactoryOrTestTemplateMethods(IsTestClassWithTests.java:50)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.test(IsTestClassWithTests.java:46)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:67)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:135)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1632)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:189)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:126)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:92)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 52 more
```

Unfortunately, this is where I get stuck. When I add `-X` I see that both the API and core modules are added to the module path both when compiling and when running the tests. This is from the `surefireargs` file that's created:

```
--module-path
"D:\\Code\\Java\\github\\misc\\junit-support\\target\\classes;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\jupiter\\junit-jupiter-api\\5.9.0\\junit-jupiter-api-5.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\platform\\junit-platform-commons\\1.9.0\\junit-platform-commons-1.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\jupiter\\junit-jupiter-params\\5.9.0\\junit-jupiter-params-5.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\hamcrest\\hamcrest\\2.2\\hamcrest-2.2.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\mockito\\mockito-core\\4.8.0\\mockito-core-4.8.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\com\\github\\robtimus\\io-functions\\2.0\\io-functions-2.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-api\\2.19.0\\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\logging\\log4j\\log4j-core\\2.19.0\\log4j-core-2.19.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\ch\\qos\\logback\\logback-classic\\1.4.5\\logback-classic-1.4.5.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\ch\\qos\\logback\\logback-core\\1.4.5\\logback-core-1.4.5.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\slf4j\\slf4j-api\\2.0.4\\slf4j-api-2.0.4.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\ch\\qos\\reload4j\\reload4j\\1.2.23\\reload4j-1.2.23.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\opentest4j\\opentest4j\\1.2.0\\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apiguardian\\apiguardian-api\\1.1.2\\apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar"
--class-path
"D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-booter\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-booter-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-api\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-api-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-logger-api\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-logger-api-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-shared-utils\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-shared-utils-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-extensions-spi\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-extensions-spi-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Code\\Java\\github\\misc\\junit-support\\target\\test-classes;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\jupiter\\junit-jupiter\\5.9.0\\junit-jupiter-5.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\jupiter\\junit-jupiter-engine\\5.9.0\\junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\platform\\junit-platform-engine\\1.9.0\\junit-platform-engine-1.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\net\\bytebuddy\\byte-buddy\\1.12.14\\byte-buddy-1.12.14.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\net\\bytebuddy\\byte-buddy-agent\\1.12.14\\byte-buddy-agent-1.12.14.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\objenesis\\objenesis\\3.2\\objenesis-3.2.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\commons-io\\commons-io\\2.11.0\\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\platform\\junit-platform-testkit\\1.9.0\\junit-platform-testkit-1.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\assertj\\assertj-core\\3.23.1\\assertj-core-3.23.1.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit\\platform\\junit-platform-launcher\\1.9.0\\junit-platform-launcher-1.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\junit-pioneer\\junit-pioneer\\1.9.0\\junit-pioneer-1.9.0.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\surefire-junit-platform\\3.0.0-M7\\surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0-M7.jar;D:\\Programs\\Maven.repository\\org\\apache\\maven\\surefire\\common-java5\\3.0.0-M7\\common-java5-3.0.0-M7.jar"
--patch-module
com.github.robtimus.junit.support="D:\\Code\\Java\\github\\misc\\junit-support\\target\\test-classes"
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.examples.collections=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.examples.covariantreturn=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.examples.delegation=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.examples.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testresource=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.params=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens
com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.test.collections=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules
com.github.robtimus.junit.support
--add-reads
com.github.robtimus.junit.support=ALL-UNNAMED
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter
```

I've also tried opening the package of the class, but then I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Unknown module: org.apache.logging.log4j specified to --add-opens
```

So even though both Log4j modules are added to the module path, and the `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Supplier` is present in the JAR file, it can't be found when running the tests. This isn't even localized to my local machine; the GitHub action also fails: https://github.com/robtimus/junit-support/actions/runs/3558874573/jobs/5977845973

Edit: adding the following plugin doesn't fix the issue (the plugin already had the source and target set to 11):

```xml
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Since version 2.x is not fully modularized, can you check with the latest `3.0.0-SNAPSHOT`? It is available from the [Apache Repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) Maven repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives me compiler errors because of incompatibilities between versions 2.x and 3.x. For instance, https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Plugin.java has moved to https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-plugins/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/plugins/Plugin.java

Comment: We would very much appreciate feedback on 3.0 as it is getting pretty near the point where we want to release it. Since the primary motivation for 3.0 was full JPMS support the earlier we get feedback the better. Plugins should NOT need to be recompiled but if you are recompiling you will have to update your source.

Comment: @rgoers I now see that plugins have been split off to a separate module. However, with the package rename, that means that any existing plugins will (probably) not work. Was this tested?

Comment: I've found a solution, see below. No idea why I had to do this for Log4j and logback but not reload4j, SLF4J or `java.logging` though.

Comment: @RobSpoor Yes,  it has been tested but it is certainly possible that with all the changes happening in 3.0 that something isn't working. If you run into any problems would love it if you could provide the Log4j team with a test that illustrates it.

Comment: @rgoers I have tested this, and created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3640 with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by adding `--add-modules` to the surefire plugin's `argLine`. I had to add not just Logj4, but also logback, which had the same problem. In addition, because I added some custom test appenders to the logging configuration, I had to open the package to these modules as well.

The result:

```xml
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>
                --add-modules org.apache.logging.log4j
                --add-modules ch.qos.logback.classic
                --add-modules ch.qos.logback.core

                --add-opens com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger=java.logging
                --add-opens com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger=org.apache.logging.log4j.core
                --add-opens com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger=ch.qos.logback.core
                --add-opens com.github.robtimus.junit.support/com.github.robtimus.junit.support.extension.testlogger=ch.qos.reload4j

                <!-- other existing add-opens omitted -->
              </argLine>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Yes, you would have to open your packages to other modules that need to access them.

Comment: In this case it's only needed to let the logging frameworks instantiate my appender classes. The actual code only uses their public APIs as a consumer.